# Dynamically create a method from a string in ES6 javascript (non browser)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, code-generation, dynamic-code

In javascript code, I have a string that defines a property path within an object. For instance

```
var def = "contact.email"
```

How can I get the following function from this string?

```
o => o.contact.email
```

So that I can use it in the following way:

```
var person = {
    name: 'Test',
    contact: { email: 'test@test.test' }
}

var emailGetter = MagicCompileFunction('contact.email');

var email = emailGetter(person);
// here, email should hold the value of person.contact.email
```

The path string is unknown at compile time. It could be provided by the user as well.

The solution should work in non-browser environments too (where there is no `window` object), for instance in NodeJS server side javascript.

I know that one solution would be to create a generic method that takes an object and a string as arguments (`valueGetter(person, "contact.email")` for instance), where the string defines the path within the object, and then split the string on each dot '.' and follow the path on the object. But I don't want this algorithm to execute in every call to `getter` function. I need a dynamically compiled method that would give me a final getter that would access the desired (sub)property immediately.

Comment: Why do you need a final getter exactly? The solution, if you need it exactly as specified would be using `eval`, which is a terrible idea in most cases, including this one. A generic method would be a much better solution.

Comment: I would try a "generic" method and see how it performs before trying to cook up some science project.

Comment: In fact I don't even think what you're asking makes sense, unless you want to "compile" directly into the runtime intermediate code, which would **definitely** be a "science project".  Once you know the property names, it's still necessary to sequentially fetch the property values from each object in the chain.

Comment: @Pointy this is a method that will be probably be executed hundreds or thousands of times. I think a generic method that contains a string split and a for loop, to loop over each property in the path will be less efficient that dictionary look-ups. On the other hand, using a generic method would make it easier to avoid accessing properties of undefined objects, but that would add an extra if check within the loop.

Comment: If that's really the case, then perhaps you should re-think the way you're data structure is built. I mean, if there are significant performance considerations then it might be good to explore other aspects of the system that could be changed.

Comment: "hundreds or thousands of times" isn't really that high count unless you for some reason need to process these emails during an animation frame. Even hundred thousand times should be in the hundred millisecond range.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that many times a restructuring or redesigning of the system would solve many problems, or avoid them altogether, but there are also times where you don't have a say on how things are organized.

Comment: @MikkoRantanen as I said, the path of the object, or the object type are unknown at compile time. The code I provided is just for example.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/dynamic-property-lookup/1 - my numbers took that into account. The accepted answer is fastest, yes, but the safer alternatives aren't that slow either. As long as you do any currying on the parameters, you could, for example, run smooth 30 fps animation and process 100000 contacts each frame. As I said: hundred or thousand is a very small amount of data and should have no performance issues even if you opted for a safe approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can achieve this using [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)**

```
var person = {
    name: 'Test',
    contact: { email: 'test@test.test' }
}
var maginFunction = (def) => new Function('o','return o.'+ def);

var emailGetter = maginFunction('contact.email');

var email = emailGetter(person);
console.log(email);
```

Comment: This is marked as the best solution because it seems it does exactly what I want. All the other answers don't avoid loops, string splitting or array manipulation.

Comment: However please be really careful with what you allow 'def' to be here. As you said, it may come from the users and run on the server. You'll want to be extremely careful they won't give you "constructor && require('child_process').exec( 'rm -rf /' )".

Comment: Wow this is a terrible code for the job.. you must be ultra careful not be hacked as follows; `var maginFunction = (def) => new Function('o','return o.'+ def);
str = 'crash || (function(){console.log("you are f*cked")})()';
maginFunction(str)({a:"naive"});`

Comment: @Redu well "hacking" may not be an issue if it's only used with data under the site's control. What I'm trying to figure out is if a function created with the Function constructor is a candidate for optimization. (The unoptimized version of this might be faster than an iterative solution anyway, of course.)

Comment: @Pointy OP says "The path string is unknown at compile time. It could be provided by the **user** as well." Would you trust any user to modify your code on the fly?

Comment: Well then yes, that could be risky. However, in other news that function (`emailGetter`) does get optimized, in V8 at least. ([See this article.](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)).

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis Keep in mind this is a potentially dangerous approach if the strings being entered here are stored anywhere on the server. If it's just a user entering them in their own browser and never storing them, it's okay, but otherwise this is a wide-open XSS attack vector.

Comment: It is a dangerous approach indeed. The input string may originate on the user's side but it will match a certain regex before going into the Function constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly more ES6 than [Archer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43370900/1084004):

```js
function MagicCompileFunction(mapping) {
 return (obj => mapping.split(".").reduce((curr, name) => curr[name], obj));
}

var person = {
    name: "Test",
    contact: {
  email: "test@test.test"
 }
}

var emailGetter = MagicCompileFunction("contact.email");
var email = emailGetter(person);

var nameGetter = MagicCompileFunction("name");
var name = nameGetter(person);

console.log(email);
console.log(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the question so I came up with a solution.  This should do what you ask, without any need for using eval...

```js
function MagicCompileFunction(mapping) {
 mapping = mapping.split(".");
 return (function(obj) {
  var result = obj;
  for (var idx in mapping) {
   result = result[mapping[idx]];
  }
  return result;
 });
}

var person = {
    name: "Test",
    contact: {
  email: "test@test.test"
 }
}

var emailGetter = MagicCompileFunction("contact.email");
var email = emailGetter(person);

var nameGetter = MagicCompileFunction("name");
var name = nameGetter(person);

console.log(email);
console.log(name);
```

The `MagicCompileFunction()` returns a function that is primed with the mapping that you use when you create the getter object.  Then you can pass any person into that object to return the related data.

Comment: Your `for` loop probably should be a plain `for` loop and not a `for ... in`, but yes this is probably the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may dynamically access the nested object properties simply as follows;

```js
function dynPropAcc(o,s){
  return s.split(".")
          .reduce((p,q,i) => i-1 ? p[q] : o[p][q]);
}

var def = "contact.email.2",
    obj = {contact: {name: "John", email: { 1: "john@x.com", 2: "john@y.com"}}};

console.log(dynPropAcc(obj,def));
```